# Mistake in a problem solution

Tags: t-sql

I am trying to solve [this](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/projects/problem) problem from hackerrank
this far I've written this solution

```
select Start_Date, min(End_Date)
from 
   (select Start_Date from projects where Start_Date not in (select End_Date from projects)),
   (select End_Date from projects where End_Date not in (select Start_Date from projects))
where Start_Date < End_Date 
group by Start_Date
order by datediff(day, min(End_Date), Start_Date) desc
```

But it shows that this answer is wrong though when I compare I get the results I planned to get. I'd much appreciate a little help to find out where I am wrong. 
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
-- SET A MARK (RST=1) EVERY TIME PREVIOUS END_DATE IS NOT EQUAL START_DATE
WITH CT AS
(
    SELECT 
        TASK_ID, START_DATE, END_DATE,
        CASE WHEN (COALESCE(LAG(END_DATE) OVER (ORDER BY START_DATE), END_DATE) = START_DATE)
             THEN 0 ELSE 1 END RST
    FROM
        TASK
)
-- SUM(RST) TO SET A GROUP (1, 2, 3, ...)
, CT2 AS
(
    SELECT
        TASK_ID, START_DATE, END_DATE,
        SUM(RST) OVER (ORDER BY START_DATE) AS GRP
    FROM
        CT
)
SELECT 
    MIN(START_DATE) AS START_DATE,
    MAX(END_DATE) AS END_DATE
FROM 
    CT2
GROUP BY
    GRP;
```

> ```
> START_DATE          | END_DATE           
> :------------------ | :------------------
> 01/10/2015 00:00:00 | 04/10/2015 00:00:00
> 13/10/2015 00:00:00 | 15/10/2015 00:00:00
> 28/10/2015 00:00:00 | 29/10/2015 00:00:00
> 30/10/2015 00:00:00 | 31/10/2015 00:00:00
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=19da457f28d736ea0c4c6e328b7c03c0)*

Answer (score 2):

This is a gaps-and-islands problem. The extra assertion that every `end_date` is 1 day after `start_date` makes it a bit easier:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT 
        START_DATE, END_DATE,
        DATEADD(DAY, 1 - ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY START_DATE), START_DATE)
            AS GRP
    FROM
        PROJECTS
)
SELECT 
    MIN(START_DATE) AS START_DATE,
    MAX(END_DATE) AS END_DATE
FROM 
    CTE
GROUP BY
    GRP
ORDER BY
    COUNT(*), START_DATE ;
```

We could even not use `END_DATE` at all:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT 
        START_DATE,
        DATEADD(DAY, 1 - ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY START_DATE), START_DATE)
            AS GRP
    FROM
        PROJECTS
)
SELECT 
    MIN(START_DATE) AS START_DATE,
    DATEADD(DAY, COUNT(*), MIN(START_DATE)) AS END_DATE
FROM 
    CTE
GROUP BY
    GRP
ORDER BY
    COUNT(*), START_DATE ;
```